# Worklight: WL.Client.addGlobalHeader() has no effect

Tags: http-headers, ibm-mobilefirst, http-caching

When I add the line

```
WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("MyCustomHeader","abcdefgh");
```

inside of my main js file like so

```
function wlCommonInit(){

WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("MyCustomHeader","abcdefgh");
    (...)
```

like it's described in the documentation (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_addglobalheader.html) this has absolutely no effect all request send after that:

```
GET /apps/services/preview/MobileOPMClient/common/0/default/images/icons/icon_settings.png             
HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/30.0.1599.66 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8080/apps/services/preview/MobileOPMClient/common/0/default/MobileOPMClient.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1e1fig7holfdpeuc46w6jmrph; testcookie=oreo
```

Why is there no line

```
MyCustomHeader: abcdefgh
```

Background: I would like to allow local caching of javascript-files to debug them in chrome.

spyro

Answer (score 3):

Global headers are added for requests made by WL client API, for example WL.Client.connect(), WL.Client.invokeProcedure() etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you (i would upvote your answer, but I've not enough reputation yet, sorry).