# Worklight 6.1 : Globalheader API is not working in iPad

Tags: http-headers, ibm-mobilefirst

Using workligin 6.1.0 version and using

```
WL.Client.addGlobalHeader('Version', Version);
```

and getting this value on adapter side like this

```
var Version = req.getHeader("Version");
```

But i am not getting value from client side and getting null value.
I checked this on IOS7 IOS5 IOS6 but in all the device it is not working. Please check and provide the solution.

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272022/worklight-wl-client-addglobalheader-has-no-effect

Comment: @vishal_g, comments based on EusebiuMarcu's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As Eusebiu mentioned in the comments - this is not the purpose of this API method.

Per Anton's explanation in the question: [Worklight: WL.Client.addGlobalHeader() has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272022/worklight-wl-client-addglobalheader-has-no-effect)

> Global headers are added for requests made by WL client API, for
>   example `WL.Client.connect()`, `WL.Client.invokeProcedure()` etc.

So you cannot simply 'get' the header by adding it and then trying to retrieve it.
Please provide a more complete scenario and code snippets.